# How to get every attribute's name, value and parent element name in SQLXML?

Tags: sql, xml, sqlxml

Given this SQL:

```
DECLARE @content XML
SET @content =
'<people>
  <person id="1" bimble="1">
    <firstname bobble="gomble">John</firstname>
    <surname>Doe</surname>
  </person>
  <person id="2" bimble="11">
    <firstname bobble="zoom">Mary</firstname>
    <surname>Jane</surname>
  </person>
  <person id="4" bimble="10">
    <firstname bobble="womble">Matt</firstname>
    <surname>Spanner</surname>
  </person>
</people>'
```

I want to retrieve every attribute, it's value and parent element's name as a table:

```
Parent Name Attribute Name Attribute Value
----------- -------------- ---------------
person      id             1
person      bimble         1
firstname   bobble         gomble
person      id             2
person      bimble         11
firstname   bobble         zoom
person      id             4
person      bimble         10
firstname   bobble         womble
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My initial answer (to my own question):

```
SELECT
    elem.value('local-name(..)', 'nvarchar(10)') AS 'Parent Name',
    elem.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(10)') AS 'Attribute Name',
    elem.value('.', 'nvarchar(10)') AS 'Attribute Value'
FROM
    @content.nodes('//@*') AS El(elem)
```

Comment: Why not add this at the bottom the question?

Comment: Because it's an answer and the system marks you down for not having a selected answer.