# Use XML as a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, sqlxml

Using SQL Server 2016, primarily.

I have data available to me that is formatted in XML, but I need to be able to join this data to other tables in a SQL Server database.

I have looked around, but the examples I have found use a different data layout in the XML.  The examples have distinct node names in the document.  My XML has a node named `metadata` that defines the name, data type, and length of each data `item`.  In the `data` node, each `row` has `value` nodes that correspond with the `item` nodes in the `metadata` node.  Also, my XML uses namespacing.  None of the examples I have found do.  I have had problems with namespacing in other SQL/XML tasks I have worked through, so that is probably significant.

How can I use SQL to convert something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset  xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!--
<dataset
    xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/ xmldata.xsd"
>
-->
    <metadata>
          <item name="Task" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
          <item name="Task Number" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
          <item name="Group" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
          <item name="Work Order" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <row>
            <value>3361B11</value>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>01</value>
            <value>MS7579</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>3361B11</value>
            <value>2</value>
            <value>50</value>
            <value>MS7579</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>3361B11</value>
            <value>3</value>
            <value>02</value>
            <value>JA0520</value>
        </row>
    </data>
</dataset>
```

...into a tabular format like...

| Task | Task Number | Group | Work Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3361B11 | 1 | 01 | MS7579 |
| 3361B11 | 2 | 50 | MS7579 |
| 3361B11 | 3 | 02 | JA0520 |

...so I can join it to other data.

I think the first step would be to query the `metadata` node to get the column name, data type, and length.

input (boiled down)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset  xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <metadata>
          <item name="Task" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
          <item name="Task Number" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
          <item name="Group" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
          <item name="Work Order" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
    </metadata>
</dataset>
```

output

| id | name | type | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task | string | -1 |
| 2 | Task Number | string | -1 |
| 3 | Group | string | -1 |
| 4 | Work Order | string | -1 |

Once that is obtained, the next part would be generated dynamically using those values.

In case it is helpful for fiddling, here is a SQL statement that produces the desired result:

```
with
xlTask as (
  select *
  from (
    values
      ('3361B11', '1', '01', 'MS7579')
    , ('3361B11', '2', '50', 'MS7579')
    , ('3361B11', '3', '02', 'JA0520')
  ) q ([Task], [Task Number], [Group], [Work Order])
)
select *
from xlTask
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dynamic solution from your sample data:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/')
SELECT  @SQL = N'WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT ''http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/'')
SELECT '
 + STRING_AGG('c.value(''(value[' + T.X.value('let $i := . return count(/dataset/metadata/item[. << $i]) + 1', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') + N']/text())[1]'', ''VARCHAR(20)'') AS '
 + QUOTENAME(T.X.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)')) , ',')
 + N'
FROM @xml.nodes(''/dataset/data/row'') AS t(c)'
FROM    @xml.nodes('/dataset/metadata/item') as T(X);
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@xml XML', @xml = @xml
```

It reads the metadata and generates sql that reads actual rows and creates proper aliases

Comment: SQL magic.  Perfect.  Now I'll just need to rewrite the `STRING_AGG` part to work in SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution.

It will work on the condition if all `<value>` XML elements always have the same sequential order, from 1 to 4.

After that having data as a relational/rectangular dataset you can join it with real tables/views in the database.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
'<dataset xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <metadata>
        <item name="Task" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
        <item name="Task Number" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
        <item name="Group" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
        <item name="Work Order" type="xs:string" length="-1"/>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <row>
            <value>3361B11</value>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>01</value>
            <value>MS7579</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>3361B11</value>
            <value>2</value>
            <value>50</value>
            <value>MS7579</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>3361B11</value>
            <value>3</value>
            <value>02</value>
            <value>JA0520</value>
        </row>
    </data>
</dataset>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/')
SELECT c.value('(value[1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Task
    , c.value('(value[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [Task Number]
    , c.value('(value[3]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [Group]
    , c.value('(value[4]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [Work Order]
FROM @xml.nodes('/dataset/data/row') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

| Task | Task Number | Group | Work Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3361B11 | 1 | 01 | MS7579 |
| 3361B11 | 2 | 50 | MS7579 |
| 3361B11 | 3 | 02 | JA0520 |

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak. That only works if I know what the metadata node contains for each document and want to manually create a different query for each document.  The number of value nodes per row varies and their names, data types, and lengths vary.  How could this be done dynamically?  I'm thinking dynamic SQL.  I could start with something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193956/how-to-get-every-attributes-name-value-and-parent-element-name-in-sqlxml, but there's no description.  ...and I'm guilty of not wanting to endure an entire semester of XQUERY to answer one question.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: OK.  Added SQL Server version.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the ordering you can pull that out of the `metadata` node, and pass it in to predicates using the `sql:column` function.

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support the returning the `position(.)` XQuery function outside a predicate, so we need to hack it by counting nodes.

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/')
SELECT
  c.value('(value[position() = sql:column("pos.Task"      )]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Task,
  c.value('(value[position() = sql:column("pos.TaskNumber")]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS TaskNumber,
  c.value('(value[position() = sql:column("pos.Group"     )]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [Group],
  c.value('(value[position() = sql:column("pos.WorkOrder" )]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS WorkOrder
FROM (
    SELECT
      Task       = md.md.value('let $i := item[@name = "Task"       ][1] return count(./item[. << $i]) + 1', 'int'),
      TaskNumber = md.md.value('let $i := item[@name = "Task Number"][1] return count(./item[. << $i]) + 1', 'int'),
      [Group]    = md.md.value('let $i := item[@name = "Group"      ][1] return count(./item[. << $i]) + 1', 'int'),
      WorkOrder  = md.md.value('let $i := item[@name = "Work Order" ][1] return count(./item[. << $i]) + 1', 'int')
    FROM @xml.nodes('dataset/metadata') md(md)
) pos
CROSS APPLY @xml.nodes('/dataset/data/row') AS t(c);
```

The logic is as follows:

- Within a subquery:

  - In XQuery, take the `metadata` node, and look for a descendant `item` which has `name = "Task"` and so on. Assign that node to `$i`.
  - Return the count of `item` nodes that are before `$i` plus one.
  - And so on for each column name.
- Then shred the rest of the XML as normal.
- In the predicates, use `position() = sql:column("YourColumnName")` which gives us the previously calculated position.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/WuJuwW0o)

---

If you want a **completely dynamic** solution, with dynamic column names, then you need dynamic SQL.

```sql
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max);

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/')
SELECT
  @cols = CAST(@xml.query('
  text {
    for $i in dataset/metadata/item
    return concat(
      ", c.value(''(value[",
      string(count(./item[. << $i]) + 1),
      "]/text())[1]'', ''VARCHAR(100)'') AS [",
      $i/@name,
      "]
 "
    )
  }
  ') AS nvarchar(max));

SET @cols = STUFF(@cols, 1, 2, N'');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT ''http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/'')
SELECT
    ' + @cols + '
FROM @xml.nodes(''/dataset/data/row'') AS t(c);
';

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@xml xml',
  @xml = @xml;
```

Note that `sp_executesql` is used, in order to pass the `@xml` variable all the way through.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/GnA6O6CA)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to create something to convert any XML to a SQL Table and then use SQL to extract the data

You can try the following:

```
USE:

select *  from Utility.FlattenXml('your xml’)
    
PROCEDURE:

USE [YOUR_DB] GO SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO
 
CREATE FUNCTION [Utility].[FlattenXml](@xmlDoc XML)   RETURNS TABLE 
 AS RETURN  WITH CTE AS (

SELECT 
        1 AS lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
        CAST(1 AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS FullPath,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
        + N'[' 
        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)  
        + N']' AS XPath,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Tree,  
        x.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value,  
        x.query('.') AS this,         
        x.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(CAST(1 AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS Sort,  
        CAST(1 AS INT) AS ID  
FROM @xmlDoc.nodes('/*') a(x)  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
        p.lvl + 1 AS lvl,  
        c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(p.Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
        CAST(p.Position AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        CAST(p.FullPath + N'/' + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FullPath,  
        CAST(p.XPath + N'/'+ c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')+ N'['+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)+ N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XPath,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        CAST( SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE(N'-', 1) + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Tree,  
        CAST( c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS Value, c.query('.') AS this,  
        c.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(p.Sort + CAST( (lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX) ) AS Sort,  
        CAST((lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS INT)
        
FROM CTE p  
CROSS APPLY p.t.nodes('*') b(c)), cte2 AS (  
                                            SELECT 
                                            lvl AS Depth,  
                                            Name AS NodeName,  
                                            ParentName, 
                                            ParentPosition, 
                                            NodeType,  
                                            FullPath,  
                                            XPath,  
                                            Position, 
                                            Tree AS TreeView,  
                                            Value,  
                                            this AS XMLData,  
                                            Sort, 
                                            ID
                                            FROM cte  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
        p.lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        p.Name, 
        p.Position, 
        CAST(N'Attribute' AS NVARCHAR(20)),  
        p.FullPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        p.XPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        1, 
        SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE('-', 1)  
        + N'@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        x.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        NULL,  
        p.Sort,  
        p.ID + 1  
FROM CTE p  
CROSS APPLY this.nodes('/*/@*') a(x)  
)  

SELECT into [your table]
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort, ID) AS ID,  
        ParentName, ParentPosition,Depth, NodeName, Position,   
        NodeType, FullPath, XPath, TreeView, Value, XMLData 
FROM CTE2
```